# Batch Script To Extract Lines Between SpecificWords

Tags: batch-file

I have an input file ->

start of log file

```
on entry.....  
transition....  
state .....  
some logs....  
**** PRINT   
Entry  
....  
.....  
ID = 1234    
....    
    ****  
log...  
some other logs...
**** PRINT   
Middle  
....  
.....  
ID = 1234  
.....  
    ****
```

goes on.... other logs

now in my output file, I'm looking for all lines from `**** PRINT` to `****` for the cases where my ID matches `(ID = 1234)` with in the `PRINT` section

```
@echo off  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "**** PRINT" rc_p.20420_09_187.log') do (  
set "line=%%a"  
for /F "delims=<,{}" %%b in ("!line!") do echo %%b  
)) > result.txt
```

With the above code, I could get the **** PRINT, **** lines but not the lines between the two.

Comment: I just have to make sure that the lines with `****` have no spaces before the `*`'s right?

Comment: right, no spaces before the *'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's an attempt which uses a temporary directory:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
set out=0
set var=
md temp
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (log.txt) do (
 set var=
 set var=%%~a
 if !out!==0 (
  if "!var: =!"=="****PRINT" (
   set /a count+=1
   set out=1
   Echo !var! >> temp\!count!.tmp
  )
 ) else (
  if "!var: =!"=="****" (
   set out=0
   Echo !var! >> temp\!count!.tmp
  ) else (
   Echo !var! >> temp\!count!.tmp
  )
 )
)
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /R "ID.*1234" "temp\*.tmp"') do type %%a >> output.txt
RMDIR /S /Q temp
```

To change the target ID edit this part of the file:

```
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /R "ID.*1234" "temp\*.tmp"') do type %%a >> output.txt
                                          ^^^^^^^^
                                 Change this number to change ID
```

Which using the test data created a new file called `output.txt` which contains:

```
**** PRINT    
Entry   
....   
.....   
ID = 1234     
....     
****   
**** PRINT    
Middle   
....   
.....   
ID = 1234   
.....   
****
```

Note if your log file is not named `log.txt` you can edit the file to search whatever name you want.

Comment: Thanks Mona. I'm able to pull the lines within the specific words/strings. I also need to add **** PRINT & **** to the file. ID match - pulls all IDs. The log has multiple IDs and need to pull PRINT statements only for specific IDs. I have IDs without "=" sign as well... ID 1234.

Comment: @Kitcha I've edited it to allow for ID's without an equal's sign. I've also made it include the `Print` and `****`

Comment: It works Mona. Thanks a lot. It takes around 4-5mins to execute a 10MB log file. Is there any way we can speed up the process?

Comment: @Kitcha a 10MB log file is quite big. Also, batch is a pretty slow language and is not reputed for its speed. Most of the solutions here would take the same amount of time for a file so big. If you want a faster solution I would recommend using a programming language like python with regex which would be alot faster. Feel free to ask another question on SO and comment the link here and I can try to do it for you. Other then that if you found my solution helpful please mark it correct.

Comment: @Monacraft: Well, although Batch files certainly are not fast, this point is _not_ inherent to Batch file processing, but mainly depends on the way a particular Batch file is written. For example, if a Batch file make heavy use of slow techniques, like append individual lines to a file (that requires to open/seek EOF/write/close the file _for each line written_, or use external commands (like findstr.exe), it will run slower than another Batch file that don't create disk files and use internal commands only...

Comment: Thanks Mona. Does python require a software or any platform install? I can't install any third party software on a server.

Answer (score 0):

This Batch file do what you want:

**EDIT**: I modified the code, so the equal-sign in `ID` line is optional.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "IDfound="
set i=0
(for /F "delims=" %%A in (rc_p.20420_09_187.log) do for /F "tokens=1-2 delims== " %%a in ("%%A") do (
   if !i! gtr 0 (
      set /A i+=1
      set "line[!i!]=%%A"
   )
   if "%%a" equ "****" (
      if /I "%%b" equ "PRINT" (
         set i=1
         set "line[1]=%%A"
      ) else if defined IDfound (
         for /L %%i in (1,1,!i!) do echo !line[%%i]!
         echo --------------------------------------
         set "IDfound="
         set i=0
      )
   ) else if /I "%%a %%b" equ "ID 1234" set IDfound=1
)) > result.txt
```

Output example:

```
**** PRINT
Entry
....
.....
ID = 1234
....
    ****
--------------------------------------
**** PRINT
Middle
....
.....
ID = 1234
.....
    ****
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini. Output file has only dashes "------". Am I missing something here?

Comment: Excuse me? I copied your example log file from this site, pasted it to a file with the same name of your log file, run my Batch file and get the output example I posted here. Did you tried to do _exactly_ the same thing?

Comment: My bad Aacini. It works for the input sample I provided. I must have changed some thing in the file. Actually, I have a very big log file to extract the info. In order to execute the log file, changing token to * & ID to "ID. *1234" should work?

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understood your last comment. I read your comments in other answers and I _guess_ that the equal sign in ID line is optional (this is the type of details that you _must_ post in your original question. _Please_, modify your original question accordingly; otherwise it seems that you provide accurate info just to _certain_ answers). I modified my code in order to made optional the equal-sign in ID line. Please, test my modified code and report the result.

Comment: Thanks Aacini. The code works fine for the sample file provided. Now, if I need to run it against my big log file, do I need to make any changes? I changed the name of the log, ID parameters to match the log but didn't get an output.

Comment: Log file sample -> 10:53:40.455 {Metric:3} METRIC <log id='SN89SRGC952094' expr='0K000094: Inside Entry Block: getServer' label='' level='1' thread='5608' />
10:53:40.455 {Metric:3} METRIC <log sid='SN89SRGC952094' expr='
****PRINT
SUB GET SERVER  ENTRY          <<<<<<<<<<
 AttID  006d02
 AttTimeinSecs  10:53 PST
 Att ....
 Att ....
 Att ....
****
' label='' level='2' thread='5608' />
10:53:40.470 {Metric....

Comment: Try to get the log file sample from your last comment, so you realize why you must _not_ post data in comments! Why you don't just edit the original question and include a larger sample of the _real_ file? You may also include the point about "the equal-sign is optional in ID line" as I said before, and any information missed in the original topic...

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect application for my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). It is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. I recommend placing the script in a folder that is listed within your PATH. I like to use "C:\utils" for all my non-standard utilities.

With JREPL.BAT a single command is all that is needed, no additional batch script required.

This first version includes the `**** PRINT` and `****` lines from each block:

```
jrepl "^\*{4} PRINT\s*?\n(?:[\s\S](?!\*{4}))*\sID = 1234\s[\s\S]*?\*{4}" "$0" /jmatch /m /f rc_p.20420_09_187.log /o result.txt
```

This second version only prints the lines between `**** PRINT` and `****`, and also inserts a blank line between each matching block.

```
jrepl "^\*{4} PRINT\s*?\n((?:[\s\S](?!\*{4}))*\sID = 1234\s[\s\S]*?)^    \*{4}" "$1" /jmatch /m /f rc_p.20420_09_187.log /o result.txt
```

Your specification was not very precise - the regular expression could be tweaked as needed to get the precise result you are looking for.